# How can I detect if a phone is at a specific location such as a store or office?

Tags: gps, location

How do I perform an action when the user arrives at a physical location? Presumably with GPS. For example, walking into a member store or an office location and so on - the app would know that and pop up a message.

Comment: What platform?[‍](http://www.google.com)